# Change In Mongoose Schema File Is Not Reflected In Database

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using **Express** with **Mongoose**.

I changed my **Schema** file and tried to repopulate the **database**. But the fields that I added to the **Schema** are not added to the **database**.

Anyone experienced in dealing with schema changes in Mongoose??

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your schema and perhaps some more info, e.g. what documents do you want to store and what you are actually storing?

Comment: Yes I could. But it doesn't seem to me that it is that important.

Comment: It is a general thing ...

Comment: If you haven't inserted that particular field in the document, it wont show. That may be causing your issue. try inserting some documents with all the fields, you will be able to get all the fields from the schema

Comment: yes it did it. thank you.